# React how to add objects "id" to the URL

Tags: reactjs, url

I have a question that I'm sure is simple, but I don't know the answer to. I want to add an objects "id" to the url, so that when a button is pressed, the corresponding id is added to the url.

Here is the code where I have the object 'arr':

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import history from '../../history';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    Header: {
        background: '#C4C4C4',
        textAlign: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'center',
        height: '100px', 
        width: '100%',
        boxShadow: '0px 2px 2px #A9A9A9',
    },
    Title: {
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: '30px',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '36px',
    },
    Buttons: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    button: {
        margin: '0 auto',
        background: '#C4C4C4',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '18px',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        padding: '10px',
        marginTop: '50px',
        width: '700px',
        display: 'flex',
    },
}));

export default function HomePage() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const arr = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'squat',
            weight: 100
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'bench',
            weight: 200
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'deadlift',
            weight: 300
        },
    ];
    const newMovements = arr.map((movement) => 
        <Button 
            key={movement.id}
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => history.push("/movement")}>
            {movement.name}
        </Button>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.Header}>
                <div className={classes.Title}>App Name</div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.Buttons}>
                <span>{newMovements}</span>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
};
```

Here is the code where I'm calling the route:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch >
                    <Route exact path="/" render={ (props) => <HomePage /> }/>
                    <Route exact path="/movement" render={ (props) => <PercentPage /> } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

Right now, when I click on one of the buttons, it redirects me to the Percent page and changes the url to: '/movement', but I want it to be '/movement/1' for example. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Follow example in URL Parameters section of the router docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you would have to change the push so that it redirects to the appropriate id:

```
onClick={() => history.push(`/movement/${movement.id}`)}>
```

Second, change your Route to match it:

```
<Route exact path="/movement/:id" render={ (props) => <PercentPage /> } />
```

Once this is done, you can read the parameter from the `PercentPage` route. You can do this a few different ways, but if you are using hooks you can use `useParams`, as Tomasz described in the other answer.

---

[useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

> useParams returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access match.params of the current .

Answer (score 0):

You can use useParams hook inside route's child component. The param would be same as name in url with colon before.

```
<Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
```

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Child() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: you must be able to use this parameter if you define your array as an state:

```
  const [array, updateArray] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you say it must be simple to solve this. try adding a second parameter to the map function

```
  const newMovements = arr.map((movement,id) => 
        <Button 
            key={movement.id}
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => history.push(`/movement`)}>
            {movement.name}
        </Button>
```

Then you must be able to use it using the new parameter, with template literals

```
 <Button 
        key={movement.id}
        className={classes.button}
      onClick={() => history.push(`/movement/${id}`)}>           
      {movement.name}
    </Button>
```

Edit: you must be able to use this parameter if you define your array as an state:

```
  const [array, updateArray] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Second argument of `map()` is the index not an id